# Swizzling initWithFrame: doesn't work for objects in a NIB

Tags: objective-c, swizzling

I'm swizzling initWithFrame: and dealloc on MKMapView and UIScrollView to add and remove notification listeners to monitor connection to an external device so I can hook up additional gesture recognizers for these views, like so:

```
+ (void) swizzleMethodsForFooCategory
{
    SwizzleInstanceMethods(self, @selector(initWithFrame:), @selector(foo_initWithFrame:));
    SwizzleInstanceMethods(self, @selector(dealloc), @selector(foo_dealloc));
}

- (id) foo_initWithFrame: (CGRect) frame
{
    NSLog(@"foo_initWithFrame: called");
    self = [self foo_initWithFrame: frame];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        NSNotificationCenter * center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [center addObserver: self
                   selector: @selector(foo_connectionDidSucceed)
                       name: @"PM_connectionDidSucceed"
                     object: nil];
        [center addObserver: self
                   selector: @selector(foo_didDisconnect)
                       name: @"PM_didDisconnect"
                     object: nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) foo_dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"foo_dealloc called");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self name: @"PM_connectionDidSucceed" object: nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self name: @"PM_didDisconnect" object: nil];
    [self foo_dealloc];
}

- (void) foo_connectionDidSucceed
{
    // Add gesture recognizers.
}

- (void) foo_didDisconnect
{
    // Remove gesture recognizers.
}
```

This works great for views that I create in code, but if I declare them in an XIB my methods don't get called.  I'm using swizzling instead of inheritance because I don't want to hard-code this support - I want to be able to add it on a per-target basis.

What can I do to hook these objects so I can add my gesture recognizers for all objects of these types whether I create them programmatically or in a NIB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View objects instantiated from a NIB use `-initWithCoder:` to initialize, so I'd try swizzling that instead.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks so much for adding one more tidbit to my iOS fu.

Comment: NB: Bavarious might be more-right for stuff that doesn't conform to `NSCoding`.

Comment: Unsmarshalled nib objects receiving either `-initWithCoder:` or `-init` is described in the [Resource Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html).

Answer (score 2):

In iOS, every object loaded from a nib file receive either `-initWithCoder:` (if the corresponding class conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol) or `-init` (if the corresponding class doesn’t conform to the `NSCoding` protocol) when unmarshalled from the nib file. This is a different behaviour from Mac OS X, where custom views receive `-initWithFrame:` and other objects receive either `-initWithCoder:` or `-init`.

Since your classes inherit from `UIView`, which conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol, you need to swizzle `-initWithCoder:`.